# show menu and hide it when clicking somewhere else?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this scenario where I have `body` tag which doesn't visually wrap all content

And I have 3 `TR's`  that contains 2 `TD's` - one for the info word and one for a yellow div.

Clicking on each `Info TD`  - opens a `div`  (of it's own - position absolute).

- when I click the `Info` the yellow windows toggles.

[image]

The problem which I have :  closing the yellow div.

I want it to be closed only when I click either in the relevant `Info TD` OR outside the yellow div

[image]

As you can see clicking the `Info TD` already closes the div.

But I have problem with the outisde area of the yellow div.

this is what I've done :

```
$("body").on('click', ".tdInfo", function (e) //when clicking on tdInfo
{
    var $cached = $(this).closest('tr').find('.myDiv'); //cache the suppose to be open div
    var wasOpen = $cached.is(":visible");
    $(".myDiv:visible").hide(); //hide all previous visible
    if (wasOpen) $cached.slideUp();
    else
   $cached.slideDown(function ()  //when the yellow div open - register once to close only when :not(.myDiv) are clicked
    {
        $("body").one('click', ':not(.myDiv)', function (e2)
        {
            e2.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Parent - ignore me.
            $cached.slideUp();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

**Question**

The code above doesn't work as expected. when I click on the yellow div - it closes. I don't want it to be closed.

The only situations where the yellow div should be close is when : clicking the `TD Info` *or* outside the yellow div.

[**Full working Jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/pepatofa/3/edit)

*nb please don't try to change heights or insert another elements . this is the exact simplification of my current page. Also - I can find a solution with more JQ  but I think it should be much simpler.*

Comment: +1 only for the gifs!

Comment: @Alek Thanks, i'm trying to make it understandable as much as i can.

Comment: what about this..? http://jsbin.com/pepatofa/6/edit Did I get your point correctly..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  clicking on the yellow div closes it....

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think I fixed that, http://jsbin.com/pepatofa/7/edit

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy very nice.

Comment: This is really easy if you start over and catch all clicks, then do a little logic. **http://jsfiddle.net/grWK3/**

Comment: @adeneo Q : why `$(document).on('click'` and not `body.on..` ? I mean - it will all propgate to body...no ?

Comment: I prefer using the document, and so does just about everyone else, as the body is an element that has size while the document is *everything* !

Comment: @adeneo It seems like something logically wrong, I just noticed that while clicking on the white space above the yellow div..

Comment: @adeneo changing it to BODY - stopped working. why is that ?  the yellow div IS IN THE  BODY

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yup, that's what happens

Comment: @adeneo can u please explain why ? clicking in the yellow div DOES/should  propgate to the body. I think it's becuase Im clicking on NOTHING. while listen to document - listen to other things as well ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - yes it does, but clicking **outside** the yellow doesn't, as there are no elements there, and it's not the body, you're clicking the **document**

Comment: @adeneo Thanks ( p.s you really hate jsbin... aren't you :-))

Comment: I don't hate it, but I'm just so used jsFiddle and work faster there.

Comment: @adeneo Now I must change all future elements via `$("body").on(...,"selector",..)` to document listening... ;-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - lol, at least you should. I think jQuery consistently uses `document` in the examples, and it is a little confusing that the `document` is *"bigger"* than the `body`, but it really is, it catches everything, while `body` neccessarely doesn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.td').length > 0 ) return;

    var $cached = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.myDiv');
    var wasOpen = $cached.is(":visible");

    $(".myDiv:visible").hide();

    if ($cached.length && (!wasOpen)) {
        $cached.slideDown();
    }
});
```

The `body` element *is* an element with a given height and width, as shown in the OP's example, and when clicking outside the yellow elements *and* outside the `body` you're clicking nothing, but all clicks will propogate to the `document` level so you have to listen on the `document`, not the `body`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/grWK3/1/)

Comment: `$(e.target).closest('.td').length` returns 1 while we clicking slightly above the yellow div. Its because the table is virtually present over there... I did not DV.. by the way..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sharp eyes

Comment: Yeah, there's a small positioning issue with the TD element, could probably be fixed with a little CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the click event in the yellow box element and prevent default:

```
 $('.YELLOW_DIV').click(function (e) {

    //event handled
    e.preventDefault();

   });
```

Comment: ? what about the part that it should be closed when clicking outside the yellow div ?

Comment: Detect the click event on the parent or body and close it.